# Shell command 'touch' not working in PHP

Tags: php, shell

I have below php script(test.php) in `redhat` linux.

```html
<?php
shell_exec('touch /var/www/html/test.txt');
?>
```

If I run this script in command line (php test.php) ,it's working as expected.
But if I run test.php in browser(http://hostname/test.php) it's not creating file test.txt.

I tried edit sudo visudo www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

Please help me on this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guest it's because of permission, when you run in command line you run it as your user but when you run it via browser , it runs as web-service's user, so check the the permission  of `/var/www/html/` directory and  set it's permission to `755` and change the owner to your web-service ( apache , apache2 etc you have as web serivce)

So

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/ (I'm not sure about your web-service, change it your webserice and it's group)
chmod -R 755  /var/www/html/
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP will execute that just fine. But the system then does not find `touch` in the pathes it has to search.

Easiest, is to give the full path to `touch`. On my System using command `whereis` to find `touch`

```
$whereis touch
touch: /usr/bin/touch /bin/touch /usr/share/man/man1/touch.1.gz
```

So the script would be:

```
<?php
shell_exec('/usr/bin/touch /var/www/html/test.txt');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. issue resolved by changing owner of the file as apache.